# Rendering dynamic content in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What's the diference between:

```
<% content_for :something do %>
```

and

```
<% provide :something do %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[#provide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide) works in almost the same manner as [#content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for), save that `#provide` does not concatenate blocks. That is--and the following code is cribbed from the documentation--say you have these `#content_for`s, possibly in multiple templates but defined in this order:

```
<%Qcontent_for :navigation do %Q<
  <li><%= link_to 'Home', :action => 'index' %></li>
<% end %>

<% content_for :navigation do %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Login', :action => 'login' %></li>
<%Qend %>
```

Now, the following will render both navigation items in an un-ordered list, 'Home' first then 'Login':

```
<ul><%= content_for :navigation %></ul>
```

`#provide` will not concatenate and would have rendered a list with but one element.

Answer (score 1):

Provide will send straight to the layout whereas ONCE content_for will allow addition information to be sent to the yield.

Use provide if you know you will only send once to the layout, use content_for if you will or may dynamically send more information.

It's actually a little more complex than that but the above is the shortened version.

Dave